# How to append a value to each row of the array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

As the title suggests, you can hang a value for each row of the array?
Let's say I have an array having three elements.
Each element (row) is formed by the following preparation in the cells:

```
home, host, share
```

total cells = 2 (because of part 0 in the array).
You can append the last cell, then after share, a value at will?
This obviously for each row of the array.
In such a way as to have, for example:

```
line [0] => home, host, share, 3
line [1] => home, host, share, 3
line [2] => home, host, share, 3
```

How can you do this?
I want to clarify that the array is so stated:

```
Dim array As New List(Of String)
```

I wouldn't want that now there are no problems with the last value that is an int ...

Comment: Don't name a variable the same as a DataType `array`. Why not make a custom class instead of a string array to hold multiple data points?

Comment: In the future, now I would just opt for a function.

Comment: It's never too early to refactor your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*There are much better approaches than this...see the answer by Plutonix for instance.

You can append it to the end just fine, but the int will be converted to a **string**:

```
    Dim data As New List(Of String)
    data.Add("home1, host1, share1")
    data.Add("home2, host2, share2")
    data.Add("home3, host3, share3")

    For i As Integer = 0 To data.Count - 1
        data(i) = data(i) & ", " & i.ToString
    Next

    For Each entry As String In data
        Debug.Print(entry)
    Next
```

It'd be up to you to convert it back to an int when you split that string into its different parts in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions would be clearer if you used the correct terms.  People ask so many questions before they post an answer to be sure your DataTable is really a `System.Data.DataTable` or if your array is *really* an array.  In this case you are not using an array (other than as  the variable name). It is a `List(of String)` or more generally a collection.

As a `List(Of String)` you cant "hang" or append an integer to it.  But you can change it to hold a class of the related data:

```
Class Foo               '  no idea what these are
    Public Property Home As String
    Public Property Host As String
    Public Property Share As String
    Public Property Value As Integer

End Class

Private myThings As New List(of Foo)

' add one thing:
Dim f As New Foo
f.Home  = ...
f.Host  = ...
f.Share = ...
f.Value = 3
myThings.Add(f)
```

Now, all 4 data items are at `myThings(0)`.  To get them back:

```
Console.WriteLine(myThings(0).Home)
```

There are numerous ways to collapse the above code.  It is as it is for illustrative purposes.

---

```
myThings.Add(New Foo  With {.Home ="here", .Host="ziggy",
                          .Share="none", .Value=3})

myThings.Add(New Foo  With {.Home ="there", .Host="zoey",
                            .Share="all", .Value=5})
```

`myThings(0)` is the ziggy record, `mytThings(1)` is the zoey record.  You can also use a constructor for the class (`Sub New`) to accept the args and make it less wordy::

```
 ' requires a Sub New to assign the vars!
 myThings.Add(New Foo ("there", "zoey", "all", 5))
```